# OkHttp GET and the possibility of blocking when reading body

Tags: okhttp

The [recipes page](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes) for OkHttp states that when making an asynchronous request,

> The callback is made after the response headers are ready. Reading the response body may still block.

Under what conditions would reading the response body block?  Doesn't the possibility of blocking defeat the whole purpose of making an asynchronous call?

For those who have used OkHttp, how did you deal with the possibility of blocking?

1. Ignore it.
2. Use synchronous requests and make them asynchronous yourself, e.g., in an `AsyncTask`.
3. Stop wasting time and use a different HTTP library.
4. ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Under what conditions would reading the response body block?

When the body is larger than the remaining space after reading the headers in the 2k chunk size that's used.

> Doesn't the possibility of blocking defeat the whole purpose of making an asynchronous call?

No. No one wants to write asynchronous code dealing with the processing of bytes.

When the response is received we hand you the source from which to read data from in a blocking way. Blocking IO code is much more easy to read, write, and reason about and most libraries in this space (like a Gson) are setup for blocking reads.

> For those who have used OkHttp, how did you deal with the possibility of blocking?

You just do the blocking read of the body data and then notify application code through whatever mechanism you want when it's complete.

You mention AsyncTask which makes it seem like you're on Android. The callbacks don't happen on the main thread so doing blocking IO doesn't matter.

Comment: It didn't seem relevant to the question, but until the Apache HTTP libraries were deprecated, my go-to HTTP library was android-async-http.  Now I'm looking for a conceptually similar alternative.  I was under the impression that OkHttp was designed for Android and followed Android's strong convention of calls and callbacks occurring in the main thread.  Since that's not the case, my question has lost its relevance to me.

Comment: OkHttp is not an Android library.

Comment: "Blocking IO code is much more easy to read, write, and reason about" - Not being responsible for the read at all is even easier.

Comment: "Not being responsible for the read at all is even easier." And slower. And wasteful on memory.

Comment: Those are almost always distant secondary concerns behind simplicity and clarity.

Comment: You forgot to amend "for me" to that wholly subjective statement.

Comment: Subjective, yes, but [widely accepted as a best practice](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: If you wanna fully buffer the response body & callback on the main thread, that's easy. OkHttp is intended to work for both small responses and also very large ones – like video downloads.